# Why can't I call FirstOrDefault on Descendants("XName")

Tags: .net, xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Why can't I call `FirstOrDefault()` on this XML, whereas I have other `XDocument`s where `FirstOrDefault()` is available?

```
        var actual = new XDocument(
            new XComment("This is a comment"),
            new XElement("Root",
                         new XElement("Child1", "data1"),
                         new XElement("Child2", "data2")
                ));

        actual.Descendants("Child1"). <- FirstOrDefault does not show up.
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have a `using System.Linq` directive?

Comment: Do you have the right namespaces included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include `System.Linq` namespace in the top of your **cs** file.
If you're using ReSharper, try push `ctrl+alt+space` after typing `.` and look for `FirstOrDefault`. R# helps to manage namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I had System.Xml.Linq;, but not System.Linq.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
    var actual = new XDocument(
        new XComment("This is a comment"),
        new XElement("Root",
                     new XElement("Child1", "data1"),
                     new XElement("Child2", "data2"),
            ));

    actual.Descendants("Child1").FirstOrDefault();
```

make sure you have using System.Linq in your using directives.